# Is it possible to push an image to AWS ECR using Google CloudBuild?

Tags: google-cloud-build, amazon-ecr

The following snippet (Node/Typescript) utilizes Google's CloudBuild API (v1) to build a container and push to Google's Container Registry (GCR). If it is possible, what's the right way to have CloudBuild push the image to AWS ECR instead of GCR?

````js
import { cloudbuild_v1 } from "googleapis";

[...]

const manifestLocation = `gs://${manifestFile.bucket}/${manifestFile.fullpath}`;
const buildDestination = `gcr.io/${GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID}/xxx:yyy`;

const result = await builds.create({
    projectId: GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID,
    requestBody: {
        steps: [
            {
                name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcs-fetcher',
                args: [
                    '--type=Manifest',
                    `--location=${manifestLocation}`
                ]
            },
            {
                name: 'docker',
                args: ['build', '-t', buildDestination, '.'],
            }
        ],
        images: [buildDestination]
    }
})```
````

Comment: Follow the steps in [Pushing a Docker image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/docker-push-ecr-image.html) and see what problems you find.

Comment: To clarify, I'm looking to use Google's CloudBuild process itself to push the image to the AWS registry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can by setting a custom step where you do that.

for this you can have a step with the docker image that makes the build and pushes it to AWS ECR.

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: [ 'build', '-t', '<AWS_ACCOUNT_ID>.dkr.ecr.<REGION>.amazonaws.com/<IMAGE_NAME>', '.' ]
```

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/building/build-containers#use-buildconfig) is a guide on how to use cludbuild which can be useful to you.

BAsically on your usecase you can just change the value of destination to the AWS ECR URL like this:

````
import { cloudbuild_v1 } from "googleapis";

[...]

const manifestLocation = `gs://${manifestFile.bucket}/${manifestFile.fullpath}`;
const buildDestination = `<AWS_ACCOUNT_ID>.dkr.ecr.<REGION>.amazonaws.com/<IMAGE_NAME>`;

const result = await builds.create({
    projectId: GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID,
    requestBody: {
        steps: [
            {
                name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcs-fetcher',
                args: [
                    '--type=Manifest',
                    `--location=${manifestLocation}`
                ]
            },
            {
                name: 'docker',
                args: ['build', '-t', buildDestination, '.'],
            }
        ],
        images: [buildDestination]
    }
})```
````